# ng-model doesnt bind with text field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Consider the following JS

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.searchBooking = "test";

        $scope.goToBooking = function() {
            console.log($scope.searchBooking);
            //$location.path('/bookings/' + $scope.searchBooking);
            //delete($scope.searchBooking);
        }

        $scope.printValue = function() {
            console.log($scope.searchBooking);
        }
    }
);
```

And the following HTML

```
<div class="input-group custom-search-form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Testing" ng-model="searchBooking" ng-change="printValue()">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

My problem is that when the page loads, "test" is written in the text field, but when I change the field or press the button, nothing happens (console says "test" on every change or button click. Anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: any isolated scopes above your btn?

Comment: Why ur not using ng-click directive in button ?

Comment: There might be, I'm not sure. Did fint a solution though, se answer

Comment: This seem to be working fine : https://plnkr.co/edit/AHvstBsj3tnbbpvIR9G0?p=preview I don't see the problem. when changing text it is writing the correct value and console is showing the right value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap the value in an object. Objects are passed by reference, but simple values are passed as a copy of that value. It happened to me too several times.

Try this approach

```
$scope.myObject.searchBooking = "test"
```

So the full code will look like this

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myObject.searchBooking = "test";

    $scope.goToBooking = function() {
        console.log($scope.myObject.searchBooking);
        //$location.path('/bookings/' + $scope.myObject.searchBooking);
        //delete($scope.myObject.searchBooking);
    }

    $scope.printValue = function() {
        console.log($scope.myObject.searchBooking);
    }
}
);
```

and the html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Testing" ng-model="myObject.searchBooking" ng-change="printValue()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Find this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5339/) which is having ng-model binding in ng-change.

HTML

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Testing" ng-model="searchBooking" ng-change="printValue()">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Angular controller

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.searchBooking = "test";

        $scope.goToBooking = function() {
            console.log($scope.searchBooking);
            //$location.path('/bookings/' + $scope.searchBooking);
            //delete($scope.searchBooking);
        }

        $scope.printValue = function() {
            console.log($scope.searchBooking);
        }
}
```